# What does ord38s08-in-f14.1e100.net mean?

Tags: google-drive

This address with minor variations keeps showing up as a request to my system and I've been getting hacked. Is this how?

Comment: From the accepted answer there, "`It's Google Safebrowsing feature in Chrome.`"